# char pointer allocates random characters

Tags: c

I am writing a small C code for class that plays Hangman with an already input name.  One section requires I allow the output of the input phrase with * in the place of all letters, but not punctuation.  Similarly, at the end of the phrase, the name of the user is put in parentheses and is meant to be printed as is.  The first section of the code works fine, the first while loop which places the asterisks, but the second while loop seems to fail every time and seems to store nonsense and random characters everytime the program is run.  Here is the program I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int guesses = 3;
    int limit = 41;
    char quote[42] = "I just wrote this game in C! (Josh Masher)";
    char strArr[42];
    char *quoP;
    quoP = &quote[0];
    char *strP;
    strP = &strArr[0];
    while (*quoP != '.' && *quoP != '!' && *quoP != '?') {
        if (isalpha(*quoP)) {
            *strP = '*';
           } else if (*quoP == ' ' || *quoP == ',') {
            *strP = *quoP;
           }
    strP++;
    quoP++;
    }
    while (*quoP != NULL) {
        *strP = *quoP;
        strP++;
        quoP++;
    }
}
```

any ideas?

EDIT

I rewrote the code slightly, and erased the random character problem, but it is more complicated now.

```
int main()
{
    int guesses = 3;
    int limit = 41;
    char quote[42] = "I just wrote this game in C! (Alex Butler)\0";
    char strArr[42];
    char *quoP;
    quoP = &quote[0];
    char *strP;
    strP = &strArr[0];
    int counter = 0;
    while (*quoP != '\0') {
        if (*quoP == '.' || *quoP == '!' || *quoP == '?' || counter == 1) {
            counter = 1;
        }

        if (isalpha(*quoP)) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                *strP = '*';
            } else if (counter == 1) {
                *strP = *quoP;
            }
           } else {
            *strP = *quoP;
           }
           printf("%c", *strP);
    strP++;
    quoP++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not setting an end-marker (`'\0'` or `0`, whichever you prefer) in your string...

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler to compile your C code, by any chance: `while (*quoP != NULL)` should complain about "pointer comparison to integer" or something like that if you aren't.

Comment: You should compare `*quoP` with '\0' not with NULL. Your first loop doesn't test for '\0' character. If the text wouldn't contain any of `!`, `.` or `?` character you may run into unallocated memory area.

Comment: Hi all,
I am also working on that aspect, but the central concern right now is the random character insertion.  Any thoughts?  I changed the code around a little bit, makes it look a little sloppy, but I am no longer getting the random characters.  The code is:

Comment: int counter = 0;
    while (*quoP != '\0') {
        if (*quoP == '.' || *quoP == '!' || *quoP == '?' || counter == 1) {
            counter = 1;
        }

        if (isalpha(*quoP)) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                *strP = '*';
            } else if (counter == 1) {
                *strP = *quoP;
            }
           } else {
            *strP = *quoP;
           }
           printf("%c", *strP);
    strP++;
    quoP++;
    }
}

Comment: Are the random characters at the END of your string, by any chance? Read my first comment, if that is the case...

Comment: And PLEASE update the original post if you have different code you want to show, as comments with code in turn to complete rubbish.

Comment: So, if you have fixed the random character problem (although I don't see where you terminate the second string...), what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add *strP = '\0' after the last while loop to terminate the string.

Also, (*quoP != NULL) should be (*quoP != '\0') .  The type of NULL is pointer, the type of *quoP is character.  Your program will still work, but it's misleading.

Also might want to include ctype.h

Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop doesn't work fine.  If it encounters unhandled punctuation (such as `&`), it will skip right over and leave junk there.

You do not null-terminate the string either, as others have pointed out in the comments.  You would do better to copy the string first (with `strncpy`) and then stamp characters with `*` as you deem appropriate.  That means you only have one loop, and it'll be a lot simpler:

```
strncpy( strArr, quote, sizeof(strArr) );
for( char *s = strArr; !strchr(".!?", *s); s++ )
{
    if( isalpha(*s) ) *s = '*';
}
```

Also, `NULL` is a pointer.  Null-termination is an unfortunate name for this.  You can write the value `0` or `'\0'`, but not `NULL`.